# Тире в предложении. К какому правилу относится постановка тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Однако это – заблуждение, точнее говоря, дело обстоит не совсем так.

Answer (score 1):

**Однако это – заблуждение, точнее говоря, дело обстоит не совсем так.**

Тире здесь **интонационное, авторское,** обозначает увеличенную паузу.

По обычным правилам тире не ставится, если подлежащее выражено местоимением, например: На самом деле это заблуждение. Это заблуждение, могу утверждать как специалист.

Обоснованность постановки интонационного тире проверяется по контексту. В данном случае можно сказать, что тире больше подходит **для союза НО, чем ОДНАКО.**

В этом случае **пауза выглядит естественнее** (следует учесть, что на "это" перед паузой должно падать логическое ударение):

**Но Это – заблуждение, точнее говоря, дело обстоит не совсем так.**

Comment: В дополнение к сказанному выше: по-моему, про наличии тире требуется также увеличить паузу после слова *заблуждение*, поэтому я бы поставил после него точку или хотя бы точку с запятой.

Comment: Да, с интонацией здесь есть проблемы, надо редактировать, например: Однако это – заблуждение,  а точнее говоря,  дело обстоит не совсем так.

Answer (score 1):

Полное предложение выглядит так:
*Как-то принято считать, что русский язык, если ему не хватает какого-то важного слова, просто одалживает его у другого языка, прежде всего у английского. Ну, например, в области компьютеров и интернета, казалось бы, только так и происходит. Слова компьютер, монитор, принтер, процессор, сайт, блог и многие другие заимствованы из английского. **Однако это — заблуждение, точнее говоря, дело обстоит не совсем так или, по крайней мере, не всегда так.** Это можно показать на примере своего рода ІТ-зверинца. Названия трех животных — мышь, собачка и хомяк — приобрели новые «компьютерные» значения, причем совершенно разными путями.*
[**М. А. Кронгауз. Ключевые слова эпохи**](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/klyuchevye-slova-epohi)

В этом контексте я бы не стала ставить тире (не вижу причин, да и правилами оно не предусмотрено). Но вот спорить с автором, доктором филологических наук, я, конечно, не буду.

После долгих исканий нашелся единственный похожий пример:
*Традиционно ковбои ассоциируются с Техасом. Точнее говоря, с бескрайними прериями в южной части страны. Для многих (в том числе и для жителей США) эта ассоциация стала настолько устойчивой, что они думают, будто ковбои появились именно в Америке, а не были «импортированы» туда из Европы. **Однако это – не более чем заблуждение.***

P.S. Если Вы предоставляете в вопросе "чужое" предложение, то необходимо оформлять его как неполную цитату:
"Однако это – заблуждение, точнее говоря, дело обстоит не совсем так..."

Comment: Хорошо, что Вы "раскопали" первоисточник. И нехорошо, если задающий вопрос не "раскрывает все карты".